# Auto populate per user information from a SharePoint List

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-selected-items

Is it possible to auto populate per user information from a SharePoint List?

I have a form with the following text input

Payroll Name
Job Title Description
Home Department Description
Location Description
Reports To Name
Work Contact: Work Email

Also have a SharePoint list with all the users information data with the column above.

Wanted to see if there is way to auto populate that user information once they open up the form.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be possible.

1. Make the connection to SharePoint list where the users info are stored.
2. In the form you want to pre-populate information select a card e.g. Payroll Name
3. Change the Default property of that card for something like

> First(Filter('User Info List', username = currentUser)).PayrollName

- 'User Info List' is the connection name
- username is a column in that list
- "user" is the information you are matching to find list items
- Since filter returns a table we use **First** to get a record
- currentUser is the variable that has the user's e-mail

You can get the current user details by using and store that OnVisible for that screen

> User().Email
>
> Set(currentUser,User().Email)

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know. Thank you @Murilo Santana

Comment: l'm trying right now. I will keep you posted. Since they are telling me is due by tomorrow

Comment: Awesome! Would be great if you marked that as the correct answer :)

Comment: Done :) Sorry crazy day